# for ajax data insertion in page what is faster than innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, dom

I'm doing an ajax work where web service will return data and on client side and I am creating html table with data.
I am using var (to hold string of generated html code), do string concatenations to generate table, tr and td tags and put data in it. Then I put this html table with data into a div using innerHTML. Please note I am applying inline css in this dynamic html code.

The issue I am facing is the web service will return a huge amount of data. What I tested is even on local machine it took about 10-12 minutes to process (concatenating, creating tags putting data in table, applying css) 10000 rows. Stored procedure just take 3-4 seconds in returning data. Please guide me how this in-browser processing time can be reduced ? I am doing it for speed in some wrong way ? Or is there some technique for it or some method faster than innerHTML and string concatenations ?

thanks

Comment: You can walk the DOM and add nodes one by one. I don't know if it'll be faster, but at least for the end user it will look like the computer is responsive. 10-12 minutes of nothing happening is too much

Comment: Is the Webservice data returned in one go? or some form of resursive call? If you use some form of network trace, how long does it take for the Webserver call to return (from start to finish)...

Comment: david data comes in one go. I have tested on local machine so it do not take much time. On remote hosting it take more time

Comment: What format is your webservice returning...in the interests of reducing your time, could you return it in a format that doesn't require (as much) DOM manipulation...for example XML with XSLT or plain old html?

Comment: it is JSON but if I return html sure data size will be increased. please adivce.

Comment: it sounds like your already returning a truck load of data...if your DOM manipulation time is really 10 minutes, I'm sure the client would be happy to wait downloading the HTML if it took them 3 minutes instead of 12...Perhaps implementing some form of paging might be a good mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I tested is even on local machine it took about 10-12 minutes to process (concatenating, creating tags putting data in table, applying css) 10000 rows

That's a whole lot of data to display in the browser. Specially once you make it remote.

Why are you trying to show so much data on the browser in the first place, I think there is something off in the whole idea.

I suggest describing more of your scenario, but this will probably become a non issue once you are working with a normal amount of data to display on a browser page.

Answer (score 2):

It's often a lot faster to create an element first, and then append it to the DOM after. Try this:

```
if (document.createTextNode) {
    // Create the element
    var txtNode = document.createTextNode("Hello. This is a new node."); 
    // Append it to another object
    document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(txtNode);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` is supposedly faster than DOM manipulation (I have never tested it myself, but that's what I read at several places). Also, pushing strings into an array then joining is supposedly a lot faster on IE than concatenation.